# show subsections in the outline

Tags: sectioning

I have been trying to show my subsections in the out line but could not manage to do it.
I used the following command:

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
```

I can see all my subsections in the chapter but can not see them in the outline. Am I missing something? I see up to the subsubsection. I do not see \paragraph and \subparagraph in my outline.

```
\documentclass{report}
\chapter{sectioning}
\listfiles

\makeindex
\begin{document}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\section{titles}
\subsection{subtitles}
\subsubsection{subsubtitles}
\paragraph{subsubsubtitles}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Still no [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)?

Comment: Hi! As @Werner points out, having asked 12 questions before, you should understand how important MWEs are.

Comment: @tohecz And only one of them accepted (altough is true that not all of them have been answered).

Comment: @tohecz it is not very clear how to accept an answer that was given as a comment. I was puzzled about this and alternatively, I was thanking people who answered me in comments all the times. Werner and Tohecz, I did not know that such a question will need a MWE.There should be a command to include paragraphs and sub paragraphs in the outline.

Comment: @Naema First, to get subparagraphs into your table of contents you need the depths to be 5 rather than 4. Second, almost any question can be improved with a good MWE, but surely one is needed when someone who wants to help suggests you provide one. This is especially true for this question because the `\setcounter` commands that you have given are precise what most of us have used many times to get what it is you claim you are not getting. That fact indicates something has gone wrong with something that is not in your question, but would have to be in the MWE.

Comment: @Naema: Before the edit there was no mention of the document class that you're using (which could influence the setup in your table of contents), nor of any packages that you might be inclined to use/are using at the moment. Now, with the piece of code you've added it is obvious that this is *not* an example you're using... `\chapte` is not a valid command, nor does it fit in the preamble. Moreover, since you're interest is in the structure of the ToC, why don't you include *at least* `\tableofcontents`? Please follow the following link: [MWE](http://goo.gl/dtPzv).

Comment: @Naema: Regarding answers in comments, see [What if a comment answers a question?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1731/5764) We're not out to hurt your reputation here, we're just interested in a little help to showcase what you're currently using so that we can help you efficiently. Have a MWE means I can copy-and-paste it into my editor and compile and see exactly what you're experiencing in terms of problems even though I'm on the opposite side of the globe. Then, once we're on the same page, we can move towards a solution.

Comment: Dan , I use a ready template to write my thesis. I tried to do MWE but could not because when I write the MWE in a new file and try ti compile it, it compiles all my thesis not just the MWE even though when I save the MWE file on a different location on my computer. Thus, I can not test my MWE before posting it. Right now, I only have up to the paragraphs, did not use subparagraphs yet.

Comment: @Naema That's what a *minimal compilable example* is. You *need* to work a little bit, to offer something that people can compile in their computers and reproduce the exact problem/whatever you see/need. You start from your whole thesis, deleting everything which is not necessary (also packages), until you end with compilable code that *does* reproduce your problem. Then you can say “There, page 2, top right corner, I would like that, but I get that”. **EDIT:** By the way, if you have answered questions that you haven't accepted, it's never late to do so ;)

Comment: @Naema: If you're interested, see [How do you accept an answer?](http://goo.gl/hzFkJ)

Comment: I gave up, I deleted all my thesis and kept only the staff I need to show the problem. My name and the subsections are still showing with their original names even after I deleted them and changed their names!!.

Comment: Someone gave me this answer "To include this in your table of contents, you have to declare \setcounter{tocdepth}{4} and \setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}" which I already used but it did only show the subsubsubsection numbers in the document not in the table of contents.

Comment: Please test your examples before posting. The code in this question produces `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.` as `\chapter` is used in the preamble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the MWE. I'm not entirely sure what an "out line" is. Do you mean a table of contents? If so then you need to change the `tocdepth` and insert `\tableofcontents`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\listfiles

\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{sectioning}
\section{titles}
\subsection{subtitles}
\subsubsection{subsubtitles}
\paragraph{subsubsubtitles}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

It's possible (but not at all clear) that you mean the PDF bookmarks/outline rather than the table of contents within the page, `hyperref` has an option to control that depth.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}


\listfiles

\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\usepackage[bookmarksdepth=5]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{sectioning}
\section{titles}
\subsection{subtitles}
\subsubsection{subsubtitles}
\paragraph{subsubsubtitles}
\end{document}
```