# why this Latex template does not allow the \paragraph and \subparagraph sections to appear in the contents

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, templates

Hi : the template is below , as you see the chapters are called in this file . I have all my chapters saved separately.At the begining of each chapter, I inserted this command

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
```

to do the \paragraph and the \subparagraph sections. Please Latex members, see this template and let me know how to show the sections in the table of contents. This template produces a table of contents that does include up to the subsection level; it does not show /paragraph sections or /subparagraph sections.

```
%Template


     % LaTeX (version 2e) source for "LaTeX for Thesis and Large Documents"
% By Stephen Carr and Wail Gueaieb
% Updated 2005-04-07
%
% Parts to edit are marked by the following block:
%###################################
%## Edit this part
%###################################
% 
% Do NOT edit anything else unless you know what you are doing.
%
%======================================================================
%   P R E A M B L E
%======================================================================
\documentclass[%
12pt,   % font size
oneside,  % final version of thesis has to be submitted single-sided
%twoside, % in case you want to print a draft on both sides of the page
]{report} 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%###################################
%## Edit this part
%###################################
\newcommand{\thesisauthor}{Stephen M. Carr and Wail Gueaieb}
\newcommand{\thesistitlecoverpage}{%
  \LaTeX \\ 
  for Thesis \\
  and Large Documents
}
\newcommand{\thesistitleheadings}{\LaTeX for Thesis and Large Documents}
\newcommand{\degree}{Ph.D.} % possible values are:
                          % M.A. / M.A.Sc. / M.Sc. / MCS / Ph.D.
\newcommand{\nameofprogram}{Electrical and Computer Engineering}
\newcommand{\academicunit}{School of Information Technology and Engineering}
\newcommand{\faculty}{Faculty of Engineering}
\newcommand{\graduationyear}{2005}

\newcommand{\abstractfile}{abstract.tex}
\newcommand{\acknowledgementfile}{acknowledgement.tex}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
% Reprocess only those files which have changed recently:
% \includeonly{intro,creating,commands} 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
% Create a listing in the log of all files needed to process this document
\listfiles
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
\makeindex % activate index-making
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
\input{private/thesis-preamble} % thesis-specific settings
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
% My own command and environment definitions:
\newcommand{\program}[1]{\textbf{#1}} % program names in bold text
\newcommand{\exten}[1]{\texttt{#1}} % file extensions in bold text (use caps)
\newcommand{\cmmd}[1]{\textbackslash\texttt{#1}} % command name in tt font 
\newcommand{\enviro}[1]{\texttt{#1}} % environment name in tt font

\newcommand{\eg}{\textit{e.g.},} % some Latin abreviations in italic
\newcommand{\ie}{\textit{i.e.},}
\newcommand{\etc}{\textit{etc}.\@}

\newcommand{\mat}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathcal{#1}}} 
    % matrix names in uppercase caligraphic
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathit{#1}}} 
% vector names in math italic
\newcommand{\rv}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathbf{#1}}} 
% math bold for random variables
\newcommand{\degg}[1]{\mbox{\raisebox{3pt}{$\circ$}\hspace{-.5pt}#1}}
% command to produce a degree sign. Example: \degg[C] gives degrees Celcius

\newenvironment{definition}[1]{\begin{quote}\emph{#1}:}{\end{quote}}
  % Provides indented formal definition and emphasizes the word.
  % e.g. \begin{definition}{Reliability} ... \end{definition}

\newenvironment{where}[1]% Equation symbol lists
 {\begin{list}{}%
  {\renewcommand{\makelabel}[1]{\hfill\textnormal{##1 =}}%
   \settowidth{\labelwidth}{\textnormal{#1 =}}%
   \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
   \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
   \setlength{\itemsep}{-\parsep}}}%
 {\end{list}}
% Example:
% \begin{where}{where $E$}
%  \item[where $E$] least squares error term;
%  \item[$w$] weighting factor associated with each measured variable.
% \end{where}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
% Standard LaTeX2e packages I am using (as seen in "The LaTeX Companion"):
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx} 
    % ... if you want to include encapsulated postscript figures
\usepackage{makeidx} % ... if you want an index
\usepackage{amsmath} % ... if you need lots of math symbols
\usepackage[dvips=true,bookmarks=true]{hyperref} 
    % ... only needed for PDF generation
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
% Non-standard packages I am using (things I've written, borrowed, etc.):
%\usepackage{} % ... note that old .sty files can be included here
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
%======================================================================
%   L O G I C A L    D O C U M E N T
%======================================================================
\begin{document}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
% FRONT MATERIAL
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
\include{private/thesis-frontpages} 
% Title page, declaration, borrowers' page, abstract, acknowlegements, 
% dedication, table of contents, list of tables, list of figures

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
% MAIN BODY
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
\input{private/thesis-headings} % Specify thesis headings
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%###################################
%## Edit this part
%###################################
% Chapters 
% Include your "sub" source files here (must have extension .tex)
\include{chapter1-intro} %"What is LaTeX, Why Use It, and Where to Find It?"
\include{chapter2-creating} %"Creating Your Source File"
\include{chapter3-commands} %"Example \LaTeX\ Commands for Large Documents" 
\include{chapter4-processing} %"Processing the Source File"
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
% END MATERIAL
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%###################################
%## Edit this part
%###################################
% Appendices
\appendix
% Designate with \appendix declaration which just changes numbering style 
% from here on
%\include{useful_pkgs} %"Some Useful \LaTeX2e Packages"
\include{appendix1-help} %"Sources of Information and Help"

% Glossary
% You could use a \begin{description} ... \end{description} for this
\include{glossary}

% Bibliography 
% If done using the BibTeX program, use
\bibliographystyle{plain} % sorted alphabetically, labeled with numbers
\bibliography{bibliography/keylatex} % names file keylatex.bib as my bibliography file 
% OR, do it "by hand" inside a "thebibliography" enivironment

% Index 
% Put a \makeindex command in the Preamble if you use MakeIndex program
% and put 
\printindex % here
% OR, do it "by hand" inside \begin{theindex} ... \end{theindex}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
%======================================================================
```

Comment: `\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}` has to be _in the preamble_ before `\begin{document}` your code section shows it is not there.

Comment: David, I just inserted it and tried to compile it and I still do not have more than the subsection level. I misses the \paragraph.I get up to 1.1.1 , however, I wanted to include the 1.1.1.1.

Comment: Sorry, but is this not the same question as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188602/show-subsections-in-the-outline also by you, posted some two hours ago?

Comment: @Andrew: You were one second faster than me ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Good to know that some one is on the ball:)

Comment: in this question i put the template so that you can clearly see what is going on.

Comment: @Naema: You could have edited the other question as well, adding the template (or at least the relevant portions of it) there... ;-)

Comment: @Andrew: Certainly... and thanks for that idiom, I just learned some English phrase ;-)

Comment: I will, please in the meantime, try to see what is missing in the template to show the \paragraph section

Comment: This question is a duplicate (I voted to close) but also the example here is not useful at all, the example in the question should be  n form that people can run it to _see the problem_ the code here is unusable without lots of other files. You should edit the original question to demonstrate the problem..

Comment: @Naema: The splitted chapters and other external files are obstacles in order to help you! And no! Do not post your chapter code as well! Edit: I just saw... David Carlisle was faster than me ;-)